# Does GNU linker (ld) fail when files are in different directories?

Tags: makefile, linker, gnu-make

When I run the following command,

```
ld -m elf_i386 -T kernel.ld -o img/kernel bin/entry.o bin/bio.o bin/console.o ... bin/main.o ... bin/proc.o ... bin/vm.o -b binary img/initcode img/entryother
```

I get the following errors:

```
bin/main.o: In function `startothers':
main.c:75: undefined reference to `_binary_entryother_size'
main.c:75: undefined reference to `_binary_entryother_start'
bin/proc.o: In function `userinit':
proc.c:131: undefined reference to `_binary_initcode_size'
proc.c:131: undefined reference to `_binary_initcode_start'
```

However, if `kernel.ld`, and all the binary files are in the same directory, the link completes with no errors:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -T kernel.ld -o kernel entry.o bio.o console.o ... main.o ... proc.o ... vm.o -b binary initcode entryother
```

Is GNU linker the problem, or is this a red herring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When create `*_start`, `*_end` and `_size` symbols, corresponded to the binary data, the linker produces the prefix from its command-line argument **as it is**.

That is, the linker uses:

- a prefix `_binary_initcode_` for argument `initcode` and
- a prefix `_binary_img_initcode_`  for argument `img/initcode`.

As far as I know, it is impossible to redefine this prefix when calling the linker.

---

With `objcopy` one may create an object file with a **specific section**, containing the binary data from other file:

```
objcopy -I binary -O <output-format> -B <architecture> --rename-section .data=.initcode,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents img/initcode <output-obj-file>
```

Resulted object file then can be used for linking with. In the linker's command-line one need to use a custom linker srcipt, which specifies the placement of the binary section and creates symbols denoted its start and end:

```
...
SECTIONS
{
   ...
   <output-section-name>:
   {
       ...
       initcode_start = .;
       *(.initcode);
       initcode_end = .;
       ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late feedback. Using `_binary_img_initcode_` in the code solved the issue. Btw, how in the world did you know that? Is this mentioned in the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) somewhere?

Comment: These are just results of my experiments with embedding binary data into the ELF file. I have failed to find documentation of that specific behavior. (Well, the whole documentation for the `ld` is not so detailed as we wish). In one of the projects I involved to it was preferrable to not depend on the path to the binary file, so the approach with `objcopy` has been used.

Comment: I see, thanks! The second approach sounds more flexible, I will try to use it in the future when I am more familiar with the [codebase](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public) I am working with.